# Defining 'last' class on foreach blog posts

Tags: posts, php, loop

I'm using the following code to display the latest 3 blog posts on my front page but I need to add a `last` class to the 3rd post on the ID `blog`.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div id="blog">
  <div class="blog-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="date">
      <?php the_date(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What do I need to add to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
$count = 1;
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div id="blog" class="<?php if ($count == 3) : ?>last<?php endif; ?>">
  <div class="blog-header"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="date">
      <?php the_date(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php 
$count++;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Tried this code but it has added the class last to the first post rather than the last?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't test it.  I simplified the code to suit your purpose. You could also use the css psuedo class `:last-child`. Something like `.blog-conatiner .blog:last-child { color:red; }`.